# Django - Use different MySQL users for manage.py vs serving app?

Tags: mysql, django, security, permissions

It seems like manage.py needs more database permissions (such as index, drop, create) than my Django app would need in everyday use.

Is there a way to tell it to use one user for manage.py commands, and then a more restricted user for actually running the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should be able to use the same db twice with different users via django's multidatabase config

e.g.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': ''
},
'default_root': {
    'NAME': 'app_data',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'super_user',
    'PASSWORD': ''
}
```

}

And then you can use the --database for maintenance purposes

```
./manage.py syncdb --database=default_root
```

Here's the multi database docs

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by having a separate `db_settings.py` file which imports the main settings file but redefines the value of the database user.

Then, when doing syncdb, you could explicitly tell Django to use that settings file:

```
./manage.py syncdb --settings=db_settings
```